# Display results in twig json

Tags: php, jquery, json, symfony, twig

I have in my controller a function to make a search filter.

The search parameter is obtained from a select field of my twig template.

The selected option is passed to the controller to see where results are with that value.

The query result is returned in JSON format.

Controller:

```
public function categoryAction(Request $request)
    {
        $category = $request->request->get('category');

        $contentCategory = $em->getRepository('MyAppBundle:Content')->findByCategory($category);

        $filterContent = new JsonResponse();

        $filterContent->setData([
            'categoryResult' => $contentCategory
        ]);

        return $filterContent;
    }
```

Twig template:

```
$('#selectCategory').change(function() {
                var optionSelect = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{path('playlist_category') }}', 
                    data: '&category='+optionSelect,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(filterContent) {
                    },
                    error: function(e){
                        console.log(e.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
```

How I can display the result returned in JSON in my function 'success'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your JS code to the following. I would rather user `$.post` than `$.ajax`. And don't forget to pass `json` as fourth arg.

```
$('#selectCategory').on('change', function () {
    var optionSelect = $(this).val();
    $.post("{{path('playlist_category') }}", {category: optionSelect}, function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    }, 'json');
});
```

Comment: But where would use the saved result in ' filterContent '?

Comment: @urreta17 I'm not sure if I understand your question. But if you mean how can you access to the filterContent result, it's inside `res` variable. Just by doing `res.someValidPropOfFilterContent` will work

Comment: Like this? 

`$filterContent->setData([
    'categoryResult' => $contentCategory
]);`

and in twig: 

`res.categoryResult `

Comment: Yes, but as categoryResult is an entity object of Content, you should access some inner property. Let's say "title" is a property of Content, you can do the following: `res.categoryResult.title`